# Update Sql column with other column values in order with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update position for my player in present in table. 
This table consists of name , id, points and position.

Default value of points is `0` then position will be `Unranked`.

If two users have same points then there positions will be same.

Demo table

```
id  | name | points | position
1   | a    | 0      | Unranked
2   | b    | 120    | 2
3   | c    | 130    | 3
4   | d    | 120    | 1
```

Required result should be

```
id  | name | points | position
1   | a    | 0      | Unranked
2   | b    | 120    | 2
3   | c    | 130    | 1
4   | d    | 120    | 2
```

Query will be like for unranked `update mytable set position = 'Unranked' Where points = 0`
 How will i use points and position set query ?

Comment: What is the data type of `position`?

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't - MySQL is generally reserved for holding data, with any dynamic calculations (such as position) handled in your application.  It's just not designed to do what you're asking in an efficient way.

Comment: position is of TEXT type

Comment: Look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table

Comment: Look also at http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/   The rank window function would be my preferred way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to hold the computed column `position` in the table. The following works for all versions :

```
create table tab ( id int, name varchar(1), points int );
insert into tab values
(1,'a',  0),
(2,'b',120),
(3,'c',130),
(4,'d',120);
select t.id, t.name, t.points, 
       ( case when points = 0 then 'Unranked' else t.rnk end ) as position
  from
  (
    select t1.*,  
           @rnk := if(@pnt = points,@rnk,@rnk + 1) rnk,
           @pnt := points
      from tab t1 
     cross join (select @rnk := 0, @pnt := 0 ) t2
      order by points desc
   ) t
 order by t.id;

id  name  points  position
--  ----  ------  --------
1    a      0     Unranked
2    b     120       2
3    c     130       1
4    d     120       2
```

If you want to hold the column `position` in your table, then you can use the following `update` statement by binding through primary column `id` :

```
 update tab tt
    set position = ( select 
                     ( case when points = 0 then 'Unranked' else t.rnk end ) as position
                      from
                      (
                        select t1.*, 
                               @rnk := if(@pnt = points,@rnk,@rnk + 1) rnk,
                               @pnt := points
                          from tab t1 
                         cross join (select @rnk := 0, @pnt := 0 ) t2
                          order by points desc
                       ) t                    
                      where t.id = tt.id );
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/WYZJ29037)

Comment: Thanks Barbaros for the answer it is giving the desired results. How to update that selection in the table as well ?

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar you're welcome. Added the update case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pain.  You can get the results you want with a subquery, but that doesn't quite work in an `update` clause.  In a `select`, you can do:

```
select t.*,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.points > 0 and t2.points > t.points
       ) as rank
from t;
```

You can now incorporate this into an update:

```
update t join
       (select t.*,
               (select 1 + count(*)
                from t t2
                where t2.points > 0 and t2.points > t.points
               ) as new_position
        from t;
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set t.position = tt.new_position
    where t.points > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  what is t2 in your answer?

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar . . . It is a table alias.  It is required when a table is referred to more than once in a query -- and helpful at other times.

Comment: Selection query is giving the right result,  but update throwing error near tt /

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar . . . What error?  There isn't an obvious problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of MySQl (MySQL 8.x) supports window function then following is possible:

```
SELECT name,
RANK() OVER (
    ORDER BY points DESC
) position
FROM mytable
where points != 0
```

Selected data can be then joined for the update like in the answer from Gordon Linoff.